# Difference between 2 questions

Tags: meaning, british-english

I am filling in [this form](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/cnr/p85.pdf) and on page two there are 2 questions (Q11 and Q12) that seem the same to me but probably are not.

- Q10: Your date of leaving UK
- Q11: Are you resident in the UK for the tax year up until the date at question 10?
- Q12: Were you resident in the UK for the tax year before departure date?

What is the difference between questions Q11 and Q12? Aren't they asking same thing: if I was a resident in the UK before leaving it?

Comment: People normally fill *in* forms, not fill them *up*.

Comment: Or filling *out* forms, but yes, definitely not *up*.

Comment: @Tristan I agree that we fill them *in* in the UK, but I think they fill them *out* in the US.

Comment: Trevore, really? I don't know about that in the USA.

Comment: @Tristan See Kevin's comment.

Comment: In the US both fill in and fill out work, though you'll hear fill out more and fill in might sound weird depending on the context. But, regardless, fill *up* would not work.

Comment: In the US one usually fills in a blank and fills out a form. It makes no sense, but there you go.

Comment: The form specifically says you should read HMRC's [Guidance Note: Statutory Residence Test](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/international/rdr3.pdf). They also provide a Local Rate Helpline number if you want to ask someone who really *will* know exactly what the difference is here. I do not think this is meaningfully a question that can be answered on ELU.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fine distinctions in UK tax law, not the English language itself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. Several non-UK members answered based on the *language* of the questions: 1. "*Are* you resident ... for the ... year *up until* the date ...?" v. 2. "*Were* you resident ... for the ... year *before* [the] date?" The issue arises from the wording used - you do not need to know UK tax law to answer it.

Comment: @TrevorD: What can I say? I have no idea whether your answer is *right* or not. But if ***I*** had to fill in one of those forms, I'd read the Guidance Notes first (or more likely, just phone the number as given on the form). The only purpose of the form is to reclaim tax you've paid that you shouldn't have (it's to claim the rebate). Doubtless HMRC check what you say, since the tax you paid is all on record, and I doubt you're risking a fine by getting it wrong (you just won't get the rebate). But I certainly wouldn't take tax advice from ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I certainly didn't mean to imply that you shouldn't take proper advice before filling in a tax form, nor that one shouldn't take the steps you suggest - even in this instance. My distinction may be a fine one, but it was merely that the *question as posed* was actually asking about the *language used* on the form (which certainly could have been clearer) and its *meaning* - not actually about interpretation of tax *law*.

Comment: @TrevorD: Sorry, but I don't accept that "the language" somehow provides two unambiguously distinct meanings here. Much more than half of your answer is taken up with background detail regarding the UK tax system, and it's only meaningful to "analyse" these two questions armed with that prior knowledge, *and* the fact that we assume *there is an intended distinction* (since there are two questions). No feasible answer is going to tell us anything ***definitive*** about how English works in such contexts. It's all just subjective post-hoc rationalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the difference is probably meant to be:

- Q11 is asking about the *partial* tax year immediately up until the departure date.
- Q12 is asking about the last *full* tax year prior to your departure date.

In the UK the tax year runs from 6 April one year to 5 April the following year.

So, if your proposed departure date (I don't know whether you are talking about future or past) were 1 September 2013:

- Q11 is asking "*Are* you resident in the UK ..." from 6 April 2013 to 30 September 2013?
- Q12 is asking "*Were* you resident in the UK ..." from 6 April *2012* to 5 April 2013?

Note that Q11 uses "Are" (present tense) & Q12 uses "Were" (past tense).

---

#### Edit

Revision:
It not clear to me whether the questions are asking whether you are/were "resident in the UK" (however that is defined):

- for the *whole* of the respective tax years; or
- for *any part or parts* of the respective tax years.

I suspect that the legal definition of "resident in the UK for tax purposes" would address the issue of *how much* of the tax year you had to be here for.

---

#### Addendum

For those wondering why the British tax year has such odd start & finish dates, blame [Julius Caesar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar) (amongst others)!

The [Julian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) (introduced by Julius Caesar) had a regular year of 365 days divided into 12 months, with a leap day added to February every four years. This was subsequently replaced by the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (introduced by Pope Gregory XIII, and still in use) which omits 3 leap days every 400 years.

Although the Gregorian calendar was adopted in many Roman Catholic countries from 1582, it was not adopted in the (Protestant) [United Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_kingdom) until [1752](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style). Additionally, [from 1155](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar#New_Year.27s_Day), the civil or legal year in England had [begun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style#Differences_between_the_start_of_the_year) on 25 March ([Lady Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Day)).

In order to [effect the change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_%28New_Style%29_Act_1750#England) to the Gregorian calendar in England, the year 1751 was made a short year running from 25 March to 31 December. 1752 began on 1 January. But by that time the then Julian calendar had drifted by 11 days from the solar calendar (due to its excess of leap years), so the UK [omitted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style#Differences_between_Julian_and_Gregorian_dates) the dates 3rd - 13th September 1752, such that Wednesday 2 September 1752 was followed directly by Thursday 14 September 1752.

The British tax authorities were, however, keen not to lose any days from the tax year, so they [continued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption_in_Europe) to operate on the Julian calendar, retaining the year start date of 25th March but adjusted for the omitted 11 days, thus moving it to a start date of 5th April from 1753. Additionally, 1800 would have been a leap year under the Julian calendar, so the UK tax year was adjusted by a further day, to start annually on 6th April. (No further adjustment was made for 1900, and 2000 was a leap year under both the Julian & Gregorian calendars.)

So we still use an adjusted Julian year for our tax year, running from 6th April one year to 5th April the following year!

Answer (score 2):

Question 11 is asking whether you were a resident for the tax year that includes your date of departure. Question 12 asks whether you were a resident for the previous tax year.

For example, if your "date of leaving UK" (Q10) is today (7 Aug, 2013; I assume tax year 2013-2014), and you met whatever criteria qualify one as being a "resident" for the tax year 2013-2014 (probably living in the UK for some minimum number of days), your answer to Q11 would be "yes."  Question 12 would then be asking whether you met the requirements for being a resident for tax year 2012-2013.

Comment: Note that UK tax years do not correspond to calendar years, so a UK tax year would never be described as, say, "2013", but as *2013-14* for Q11 & *2012-13* for Q12.

Comment: @TrevorD thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the authority is looking for, but those two sentences could mean different things. The following answers to the questions explain

> Q10 - I left on November 30, 2012
>
> Q11 - No. The tax year ends on December 31, 2012. I was not a resident when I left on November 30, 2013.  I had moved to Germany on August 1, 2012, but was visiting my mother from November 1 to November 30.
>
> Q12 - Yes. I had been a resident of UK up until August 1, 2012, during the tax year before my departure.

Comment: Note that (as indicated in my answer & another comment) UK tax years **do not** correspond to calendar years: the last tax year (at the time of writing) finished on 5 April 2013; and the current one runs from 6 April 2013 - 5 April 2014 (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Question 12 has apparently left out a few key words.  I can see how you would think 11 and 12 are essentially the same.

Question 12 is likely asking the following:

> "Were you resident in the UK for *any amount of time* for the tax year before your departure date?"

In other words, even if you were resident in the UK, left, and then returned for a time before your second departure, you would evidently be responsible for paying taxes for the total amount of time you were resident in the UK.

Not knowing the particulars about the tax code in the UK, I can only speculate that you may be liable for taxes if, for example, you were resident in the UK for only six months of the year.  Let's say in one year you resided in the UK for two months, left, and then came back to reside for four more months, and then left again, for a total of six months resident in the UK.

Question 12--if I am reading correctly between the lines--is poorly worded at best, and confusing at worst.

Comment: I imagine that "resident" refers to some legal definition that is not just "any amount of time"

Comment: I'm **sure** that there is a legal definition of "resident in the UK" for tax purposes (but don't know what it is without looking it up!).

Comment: @Kevin:  You are probably right.  The 'revinooers' (tax collectors) are experts at inventing arcane and confusing definitions and putting them in small print!